# Can't plot the pair plots in the data set

Tags: machine-learning, plot, graphics, data-science, data-analysis

I am trying  to visualize the pair plots of the haberman dataset but in pair plots I am getting the pair plots with all the four columns but i want only age, years , nodes not the status plot what to do please help???[image]

Comment: Please post some code, so that people can see what libs and changes needs to done.

Comment: Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: plt.close();
sns.set_style("whitegrid");
sns.pairplot(cancer, hue="status", height=3);
plt.show()

Comment: plt.close();
sns.set_style("whitegrid");
sns.pairplot(cancer, hue="status", height=3);
plt.show()       Sir i used this code to run the pair plots but as you can see in the last line I am getting status status pair plot also which I dont want please help me out '

Answer (score 0):

We can use the var feature of seaborn library to do the same:
sns.pairplot(cancer,hue="status", height= 3 , vars=("age","year","nodes")